# .htaccess setEnv as %{HTTP_HOST}

Tags: apache, .htaccess, setenv

is it possible to do the htaccess `SetEnv` with `%{HTTP_HOST}`?

i try it like this:

```
SetEnv HOSTNAME %{HTTP_HOST}
```

but this doesen't work. 
i tested it with setting it like

```
SetEnv HOSTNAME localhost.work
```

and thats working. So it's just my configuration whats not really operating.

Hope someone can give me a quick hint why this isn't working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn’t the environment variable `HTTP_HOST` already exist anyway …?

Comment: Yes, this works as well... feeling bad rn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SetEnv` (mod_env) is for setting simple hardcoded name/value pairs. You need to use `SetEnvIf` (mod_setenvif) if you want to set the var based on elements of the request.

For example, to set the env var `HOSTNAME` to the value of the `Host` HTTP request header:

```
SetEnvIf Host "(.*)" HOSTNAME=$1
```

The `SetEnvIf` directive sets the environment variable conditionally... if the regex (`(.*)`) matches the the first argument (ie. the HTTP `Host` header) then it sets the env var.

`Host` refers to the `Host` HTTP request header (the same as the `HTTP_HOST` server variable). `(.*)` is the capturing regex that this matches against and `$1` is a backreference to this captured pattern.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

Comment: Didn't quite understand it but it works, thank you!

Comment: The `SetEnvIf` directive sets the environment variable conditionally... if the regex (`(.*)`) matches the the first argument (the HTTP `Host` header in this instance) then it sets the env var. I've added a reference link to my answer.